# GNOME shell removing actor and adding it back is not working properly

Tags: gnome-shell

GNOME 3.36

I am trying to remove the "Poweroff/logout" button from System Menu.

[image]

[image]

For removing this button, I am using the below command in Terminal

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system.menu.box.remove_actor(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system._sessionSubMenu)'
```

This works fine.

[image]

The problem is that when am adding it back with the below command, and when I select this PowerOff/Logout button.. This button is going down while popping up the sub menu of it.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system.menu.box.add_actor(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system._sessionSubMenu)'
```

[image]

How can I make it work like the 2nd Image with out restarting the gnome-shell?